# How to reduce the memory usage in using FDWaveformView?

Tags: ios, memory, crash, waveform

I am making an iOS app drawing waveform of audio file taken from media picker using [FDWaveformView](https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView).
I need only drawing wave image but no need magnifier, progressing and other functionalities.
But the app was crashed with warning "Received memory warning" in almost times.
I think it may come from working with huge number of samples.
I can see the number of samples is about 100,000 in debug mode but I need only about 1,000 samples.
Can I reduce the number of samples or fix the crashing bug?
I hope someone to let me know the way to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API, but how are you passing data to the API? Does it accept an MP3 directly or are you passing it data points?

Comment: I am passing data by directly assigning audio url as following self.waveformview.audioURL = mAudioUrl;

Comment: I am passing data by directly assigning audio url.     self.waveform.audioURL = mAudioUrl;

Comment: hmm, then there's not much you can do without re-working the API. Get in touch with them and maybe they might give you a hand with that.